# Como guardar la imagen de un perfil(del usuario) en una BD en MYSQL?

Tags: java, mysql

o algun otro ejemplo que al momento de cargar su perfil obtenga su foto.
Me imaginaba guardar mismo en el proyecto de mi app y cargar la foto de ahí pero no se como guardar una foto en mi mismo proyecto y que debo de hacer para determinar cual es del usuario logeado. No se si me di a entender

Comment: Nose si te he entendido bien, creo que quieres que tus usuarios en el perfil tenga una imagen y que despues se muestre a cada uno n?
para ellos tendrias que tener una carpeta en tu proyecto, en la cual los usuarios tendrian que ir guardando la foto subiendolas a esa carpeta al darse de alta o en el momento que fuese, guardar la ruta en la que se guarda la imagen con el nombre de la misma para que haga referencia al usuario al que pertenece,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=snLvEdKIBW0
aqui puedes ver un video que te explica como hacerlo buscado en youtube.

Comment: normalmente para guardar/cargar imágenes se usa una base de datos. Se tiene en el proyecto una carpeta con todas las imágenes y lo que guardas en la BBDD es solo un texto con el nombre de la imagen o la ruta. Ejemplo: "imagen1.jpg".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primero que todo, se pueden guardar archivos como datos binarios o bytes en una base de datos, pero no se debe de hacer ***NUNCA***.
Lo correcto es que, si tienes una tabla llamada Usuario, y ese usuario tenga un campo llamado `Foto`, este campo sea de tipo de dato `Text` o `String`, para que, cuando el usuario guarde su foto de perfil, se guarde es la **dirección con el nombre del archivo en donde este esta ubicado**.

- Digamos que en tu servidor (Que puede ser perfectamente tu computador personal o uno remoto) hay una carpeta donde se guardan las rutas `/home/app/fotosApp/`, en esta ruta se guardan todas las fotos de todos los usuarios. Cada nombre de cada archivo se verá identificado por el id del usuario, seguido la Hora y fecha en la que el usuario subió el archivo, quedando la ruta de la siguiente manera: `/home/app/fotosApp/001-12042019-010705.jpg`. Por lo cual, el usuario con el **id 001** actualizó la foto de perfil el **dia 12** del **mes 04** del **año 2019**, en la **hora 01:07:05** de la mañana. Por lo que, en el campo de Foto dentro de un registro de la tabla Usuarios, se crea un `Text`: `"/home/app/fotosApp/001-12042019-010705.jpg"`, que hace referencia a la ruta de la foto.
- Otra forma de hacerlo, y que además implica a la anterior, es crear una carpeta para cada usuario dentro del folder `fotosApp`, cada carpeta tiene como nombre el id del usuario, o algo que identifique a cada usuario fácilmente. Generalmente, como mentaba, es un `ID` o un `código`, `correo`, entre otros, por lo que, solo con guardar la fecha y ponerla como nombre de la foto funciona, por lo que, el Text que debería de ir en el campo Foto de la Tabla Usuarios para un usuario con el id **001**, queda de la siguiente manera: `"/home/app/fotosApp/001/12042019-010705.jpg"`. A mi parecer, esta forma es mejor, ya que se organizan todos los usuarios por carpeta, y cada carpeta contiene el registro de todas las fotos que el usuario ha establecido como foto de perfil.

Ahora, en el programa, para obtener la foto del usuario y colocarla en tu aplicación, lo que haces es:

1. Establecer conexión con tu base de datos, y realizar las consultas que necesites para obtener el campo de Foto de un usuario específico: `SELECT Foto FROM Usuarios WHERE id=001;`
2. Guardar esta consulta, en una variable del mismo tipo de dato que Foto, en este caso String: `String dirFoto = obtenerFotoDB(int id);`
3. Obtener la imagen y guardarla como un array de `byte` (`byte[]`), para posteriormente pintarla en un `JPanel`, `JButton` o en el componente que desees poner la imagen.